# the operator '<' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'

Tags: flutter, dart

**Can you help solve this
I have tried to put *!*
but no use**
[image]

```
 (snapShot.hasData &&  snapShot.data! < 10)? '${snapShot.data}' ??'' : 'Future in Flutter'),

 (snapShot.hasData &&  snapShot!.data < 10)? '${snapShot.data}' ??'' : 'Future in Flutter'),
```

Comment: what do you exact want to display in appBar?

Comment: If your data is `int` you can parse to int or just add type on `StreamBuilder`, if you are checking length, include that part, also make sure to handle null on data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved the problem**

````
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  info(String a) {
    return a;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: StreamBuilder<int>(
        stream: Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1) , (a)=> a) ,
        builder: (context, snapShot) {
          return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text(
                  (snapShot.hasData &&  (snapShot.data ?? 0) < 10)? '${snapShot.data}' : 'Future in Flutter'),
            ),
            body: Center(
              child: snapShot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting
                  ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
                  : const Text('Done!'),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
(snapShot.data ?? 0) < 10
```

Comment: It was not resolved and a new problem appeared [Image Error Link](https://pickle-fold-909.notion.site/Error-Flutter-e1a04069ef664924a1477fa182eb7274)

Comment: Add type parameter to your StreamBuilder -> `StreamBuilder<int>`, the reason you get the error is without type parameter, compiler don't know snapShot.data's type.

Comment: Thank you, it has been resolved